# Arduino: Issue with a minimalist cyclic state machine

Tags: c++, arduino

this is a Arduino Uno code for a simple robot.

I have a very simplistic cyclic state machine. My issue is that it resets the firmware when it should fold back to first state (State0). As far as I can tell the limits are set correctly, but obviously, I am wrong...

Here is the state machine (.h and .cpp):

```
#ifndef MChSM_h
#define MChSM_h

#include <Arduino.h>
#include "MChLeg.h" //for the actions

const int MChmachinestateMax = 5; //max statemachine
const int MChmachinestateMax1 = MChmachinestateMax+1; //max statemachine for modulo counting

struct MChSMState{
  int stateId;
  void (*stateAction)(); //pointer to function for state
};


class MChStateMachine{
public:
    MChStateMachine();
    ~MChStateMachine();
    void setState(int);
    int getState();
    void incrementState();
    void addState(MChSMState state);
private:    
    int machinestate;
    MChSMState machinestates [MChmachinestateMax1];
    void doState();
};

#endif MChSM_h
```

.

```
#include "MChSM.h"

MChStateMachine::MChStateMachine(){
}

MChStateMachine::~MChStateMachine(){
}

int MChStateMachine::getState(){
  return this->machinestate;
}

void MChStateMachine::setState(int newState){
  this->machinestate = newState;
  this->doState();
}

void MChStateMachine::incrementState(){
    this->setState((this->getState() + 1) % MChmachinestateMax1);
}

void MChStateMachine::addState(MChSMState state){
  if ((state.stateId >= 0)&&(state.stateId < MChmachinestateMax)){
    this->machinestates[state.stateId] = state;
  }
}

void MChStateMachine::doState(){
    // set LEDs according to state
    void (*action)();
    action = this->machinestates[machinestate].stateAction;
    (*action)();
}
```

And here is how the code is called:

```
// Include application, user and local libraries
#include <Servo.h>
#include "MChButton.h"
#include "MChLeg.h"
#include "MChSM.h"


// pin connections
const int buttonIndex = 2; //pin for button
const int greenLed = 3;//pin for green Led
const int yellowLed = 4;//pin for yellow Led
const int redLed = 5;//pin for red Led
const int servoPin1 = 9;//pin for servo
const int servoPin2 = 10;//pin for servo
const int servoPin3 = 11;//pin for servo

//Input stuff
String inputString = "";         // a string to hold incoming data
boolean stringComplete = false;  // whether the string is complete



//define persitent objects
MChButton theButton(buttonIndex); // declare the switch pin as an input
MChLeg rightLeg; // declare right leg 
MChLeg leftLeg;  // declare left leg

//build state machine
MChStateMachine myStateMachine;

//list states
void State0(){
    digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH); // turn the green LED on pin 3 on
    digitalWrite(yellowLed, LOW);  // turn the red LED on pin 4 off
    digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);  // turn the red LED on pin 5 off
    leftLeg.setLeg(70, 70); // set leg to 0°
    rightLeg.setLeg(70, 70); //set leg to 0°
}
void State1(){
    digitalWrite(greenLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    leftLeg.setLeg(30, 30);
    delay(200);
    rightLeg.setLeg(80, 80);
}
void State2(){
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLed, LOW);
    leftLeg.setLeg(30, 30);
    rightLeg.setLeg(90, 90);
}
void State3(){
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed, HIGH);
    digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
    leftLeg.setLeg(30, 30);
    rightLeg.setLeg(100,100);
}
void State4(){
    digitalWrite(greenLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(yellowLed, LOW);
    digitalWrite(redLed, HIGH);
    rightLeg.setLeg(110, 110);
    delay(200);
    leftLeg.setLeg(70, 70);
}


// Setup phase
//
// Brief assign functions to pins and create objects
// Details tbd
//
void setup(){
    // say hello
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Robot6 started");

    // declare the LED pins as outputs
    pinMode(greenLed,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(yellowLed,OUTPUT);
    pinMode(redLed,OUTPUT);

    leftLeg.assignLeg(0, servoPin1); //right knee - hip
    rightLeg.assignLeg(servoPin2, servoPin3); //right knee - hip 

    MChSMState myState;
    myState.stateId = 0;
    myState.stateAction = &State0;
    myStateMachine.addState(myState);
    myState.stateId = 1;
    myState.stateAction = &State1;
    myStateMachine.addState(myState);
    myState.stateId = 2;
    myState.stateAction = &State2;
    myStateMachine.addState(myState);
    myState.stateId = 3;
    myState.stateAction = &State3;
    myStateMachine.addState(myState);
    myState.stateId = 4;
    myState.stateAction = &State4;
    myStateMachine.addState(myState);
    myStateMachine.setState(0);

}

// Loop phase
//
// Brief call functions on infinite loop
// Details tbd
//
void loop(){

    //check if there is an event, if there is one increment state machine counter and mark event done
    if (theButton.buttonEventGet()==true) {
        myStateMachine.incrementState();
    }

    // set LEDs according to state

    delay(10);
    if (stringComplete) {
        if (inputString == "next\n"){
          myStateMachine.incrementState();
        }
        Serial.println(inputString); 
        // clear the string:
        inputString = "";
        stringComplete = false;
    }

}

/*
  SerialEvent occurs whenever a new data comes in the
 hardware serial RX.  This routine is run between each
 time loop() runs, so using delay inside loop can delay
 response.  Multiple bytes of data may be available.
 */
void serialEvent() {
  while (Serial.available()) {
    // get the new byte:
    char inChar = (char)Serial.read(); 
    // add it to the inputString:
    inputString += inChar;
    // if the incoming character is a newline, set a flag
    // so the main loop can do something about it:
    if (inChar == '\n') {
      stringComplete = true;
    } 
  }
}
```

I checked that I go through all states and I suppose that something is wrong with my limits or my increment but I don't find the issue. I tried setting `MChmachinestateMax = 4` but as expected this does prevent me to reach State4.

Comment: Way too much code to debug to give you a concise answer.

Comment: I expect the issue to be in the MChStateMachine::incrementState() method, I don't think that the MChSM.h and MChSM.cpp are long. The Arduino code is there so that the context is available.

Comment: Indeed, it is in the MChStateMachine::incrementState() !!! thanks for your help...

Comment: Do you really need to have a state-machine defined at runtime? First rule about microcontrollers is KISS. This just seems overkill.

Comment: @Rafael, I need this to be able to evolve later to a larger hardware with a real state machine operating in real time (with a variety of events - from terminal and from sensors). And I wanted to push this code out of the main. But as indicated above, with the help of  πάντα ῥεῖ I found my bug and code is now clean.

Comment: I see, I'm just saying that passing all these function pointers around is just one way of defining a state machine, and it can be considered overly complicated and very expensive. You could easily put all the logic in the "state machine object", and use a `switch` to alternate between the states and call the appropriate actions.

Comment: @Rafael. This is what I had before installing the state machine. This was ok with my 5 initial sequential states but couldn't grow the way I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer found, it should have been:

```
void MChStateMachine::incrementState(){
    this->setState((this->getState() + 1) % MChmachinestateMax); //was MChmachinestateMax1... this was the bug I was looking forT
}
```